# Use "having" to begin an adverbial phrase

Tags: adverbial-phrases

Is "having" in the following  sentence grammatically correct?

> **Having** his eyes brimmed with tears, my father beamed

Answer (score 1):

The verb **to brim** is not transitive, but intransitive.

> Eyes brim with tears.

yet  **having his eyes brimmed** assumes a transitive use, as that is a passive voice construction.  It is ungrammatical.

What you want to say is

> His eyes brimming with tears, my father beamed.

or if you  want an example with **having**:

> Having no idea what the answer was, he shouted out "twenty-seven".